# How to retrieve data from a form in Django

Tags: django

I am working on a weather app where the client will be entering the name of the city in a search bar, and the name will be used to gain weather data from an API. To get the name of the city from the form, I have created this condition in view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        city = request.data
        print(city)
```

however when being printed, this error occurs: `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'`

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a completely different way to do this?

Comment: Normally the name will be the name that you given in the search form. Print the request obj and see what it contains.

Comment: i edit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must get data from template like this: (name of function in views.py is something same as in url.py.

```
def something(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        city = request.POST.get('data')
        print(city)
```

data is the name of your input tag in template:

```
<input name='data'>
```

Update:
you need to have a action for your form. it includes a url. this url connect you to your view function for this form. 
also you must add name to your input tag not your form tag.

template:

```
<form method="POST" action = "{% url "url_something" %}" >{% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="field has-addons">
                        <div class="control is-expanded">
                            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="City Name" name="data" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="control">
                            <button class="button is-info" type="submit">
                                Search City
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

in url.py you must have a url like this.:

```
url(r'^something', views.something, name='url_something'),
```